# Touch position in Android

Tags: android

How can I save my touch position in a variable (Touching position on LCD) in Android , Is it possible ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: These are two completely unrelated topics, and should asked as two separate Stack Overflow questions...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth So , Isolation?

Comment: Okay isolation has been done ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override       
 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             int yTouch = (int) event.getY();
             int xTouch = (int) event.getX();
        } 
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```